# How can i pass a filtered data into another sibling component in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filtered

I have multiple places where I need to filtered out different data, I decided to create a `search` component that can receive dynamic values through `props`. The new array coming from the search component should be pass to a new component.

I create a dummy example like this one **:**

```
<SearchBar placeholder='Search project by company name' filterFunc={'pass the function that get the input value'}/>

<TableData data={'new array coming from search component'}/>
```

I try to use the `useState` hook to store the filtered data but I did not succeed.
Can you please help me with a possible solution ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that ReactJS is uni-directional - which means, data may flow in one direction - which-is from parent to child. When there is a need to move data from child to parent, one may use callback functions (which are implemented in the parent, and invoked by the child). When there is a need to pass data across siblings, the state needs to be `moved up` to a common parent. And, both/all siblings receive the callback to update the parent's state. Otherwise, one may use state-management libraries (such as redux, for example).

Comment: @jsN00b, thank you for your information. I managed to implement the desired functionality, but the result is not 100% accurate. The data information is displayed only when i start typing. When the input is clear, all the data disappear.